# Issues setting up Spring Profiles with application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

I am struggling with setting up Spring profiles with Maven for different environments.

I have two yml files : application.yml (dev) and application-prod.yml

Here's my pom.xml

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.8</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <profiles>
                                <profile>prod</profile>
                            </profiles>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.name}-deployable</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}/ext-resources</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>**/*.jar</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7.8</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <profiles>
                                <profile>dev</profile>
                            </profiles>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.name}-deployable</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}/ext-resources</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>**/*.jar</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Here's my application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 2048KB
      max-request-size: 2048KB
```

Here's application-prod.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 2048KB
      max-request-size: 2048KB
```

When I run `mvn clean install && mvn clean package -Pprod` I get a JAR file, which when ran, uses the dev profile always.

There are no other profile configuration apart from these two.